# What determines which system is used to translate a base 10 number to decimal and vice-versa?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, binary

There are a lot of ways to store a given number in a computer. This [site](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~smoler/x86text/lect.notes/represent.html) lists 5

1. unsigned
2. sign magnitude
3. one's complement
4. two's complement
5. biased (not commonly known)

I can think of another. Encode everything in Ascii and write the number with the negative sign (45) and period (46) if needed.

I'm not sure if I'm mixing apples and oranges but today I heard how computers store numbers using [single and double precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). In this everything is written as a power of 2 multiplied by a fraction. This means numbers that aren't powers of 2 like 9 are written as a power of 2 multiplied by a fraction e.g. `9 ➞ 16*9/16`. Is that correct?

Who decides which system is used? Is it up to the hardware of the computer or the program? How do computer algebra systems handle transindental numbers like π on a finite machine? It seems like things would be a lot easier if everything's coded in Ascii and the negative sign and the decimal is placed accordingly e.g. -15.2 would be 45 49 53 46 (to base 10) 
➞
111000 110001 110101 101110

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many questions here.

1. The main reason why the system you imagined is bad, is because the lack of entropy. An ASCII character is 8 bits, so instead of 2^32 possible integers, you could represent only 4 characters on 32 bits, so 10000 integer values (+ 1000 negative ones if you want). Even if you reduce to 12 codes (0-9, -, .) you still need 4 bits to store them. So, 10^8+10^7 integer values, still much less than 2^32 (remember, 2^10 ~ 10^3). Using binary is optimal, because our bits only have 2 values. Any base that is a power of 2 also makes sense, hence octal and hex -- but ultimately they're just binary with bits packed per 3 or 4 for readability. If you forget about the sign (just use one bit) and the decimal separator, you get BCD : Binary Coded Decimals, which are usually coded on 4 bits per digit though a version on 8 bits called uncompressed BCD also seems to exist. I'm sure with a bit of research you can find fixed or floating point numbers using BCD.
2. Putting the sign in front is exactly sign magnitude (without the entropy problem, since it has a constant size of 1 bit).
3. You're roughly right on the fraction in floating point numbers. These numbers are written with a mantissa m and an exponent e, and their value is m 2^e. If you represent an integer that way, say 8, it would be 1x2^3, then the fraction is 1 = 8/2^3. With 9 that fraction is not exactly representable, so instead of 1 we write the closest number we can with the available bits. That is what we do as well with irrational (and thus transcendental) numbers like Pi : we approximate.
4. You're not solving anything with this system, even for floating point values. The denominator is going to be a power of 10 instead of a power of 2, which seems more natural to you, because it is the usual way we write rounded numbers, but is not in any way more valid or more accurate. ** Take 1/6 for example, you cannot represent it with a finite number of digits in the form a/10^b. *
5. The most popular representations for negative numbers is 2's complement, because of its nice properties when adding negative and positive numbers.
6. Standards committees (argue a lot internally and eventually) decide what complex number formats like floating points look like, and how to consistently treat corner cases. E.g. should dividing by 0 yield NaN ? Infinity ? An exception ? You should check out the IEEE : www.ieee.org . Some committees are not even agreeing yet, for example on how to represent intervals for interval arithmetic. Eventually it's the people who make the processors who get the final word on how bits are interpreted into a number. But sticking to standards allows for portability and compatibility between different processors (or coprocessors, what if your GPU used a different number format ? You'd have more to do than just copy data around).
7. Many alternatives to floating point values exist, like fixed point or arbitrary precision numbers, logarithmic number systems, rational arithmetic...

---

* Since 2 divides 10, you might argue that all the numbers representable by a/2^b can be a5^b/10^b, so less numbers need to be approximated. That only covers a minuscule family (an ideal, really) of the rational numbers, which are an infinite set of numbers. So it still doesn't solve the need for approximations for many rational, as well as all irrational numbers (as Pi).

** In fact, because of the fact that we use the powers of 2 we pack more significant digits after the decimal separator than we would with powers of 10 (for a same number of bits). That is, 2^-(53+e), the smallest bit of the mantissa of a double with exponent e, is much smaller than what you can reach with 53 bits of ASCII or 4-bit base 10 digits : at best 10^-4 * 2^-e

Comment: But 2's compliment doesn't account for fractions, so is it that the hardware typically uses 2's complement and a program at a higher level of abstraction uses floating point?

Comment: You're mixing up two things here, how to write negative numbers and how to express fractions. The mantissa of a floating point number (so m in m*2^e) is expressed in 2's complement, when the floating point number is negative. There is a sign bit to know which case (positive or negative). Read more here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point